# How to configure a debezium connector at multiple tables to different topics

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Debezium  Kafka Debezium Connect was configured on PostgreSQL payments(schema) outbox(table) to Kafka topic(payments-transactions).

```
Means at Kafka Connect perform below actions
payments.outbox ==streams=> payments-transactions Topic
```

As part of the new CDC flow, we plan to configure webhooks(schema) outbox(table) to different Kafka topic(webhooks)

```
Means at Kafka Connect perform below actions
payments.outbox ==streams=> payments-transactions topic
webhooks.outbox ==streams=> webhooks topic
```

How does the Debezium Kafka connect configuration looks? Is it possible to configure two table with separate topics?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure `table.whitelist` to multiple tables of the same schema, the each table will generate a corresponding output topic.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-topic-names